# fatal error: 'boost/uuid/uuid.hpp' file not found

Tags: c++, boost, ubuntu-18.04, smartcontracts, eos

I am trying to include **boost** UUID libraries in **EOS** **smart contract**.

```
#include <string>
#include <eosio/crypto.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
```

I followed this link to install boost just changed the version to 1.73.0 :
http://janisz.github.io/2013/11/27/install-boost-on-ubuntu/

List of commands I executed are:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y --purge remove libboost-all-dev libboost-doc libboost-dev
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential g++ python-dev autotools-dev libicu-dev libbz2-dev
cd /tmp
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost/1.73.0/boost_1_73_0.tar.gz
tar -zxvf boost_1_73_0.tar.gz
cd boost_1_73_0
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
cpuCores=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu cores" | uniq | awk '{print $NF}'`
echo "Available CPU cores: "$cpuCores
sudo ./b2 --with=all -j $cpuCores install
```

After this:

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr && ./b2 stage threading=multi link=shared
./b2 install threading=multi link=shared && ln -svf detail/sha1.hpp /usr/include/boost/uuid/sha1.hpp
```

./b2 command prints

> ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/include/boost/uuid/sha1.hpp':
>   Permission denied

Then:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libboost-all-dev
```

And trying to compile the smart contract:

```
eosio-cpp documentid.cpp -o documentid.wasm
```

Its giving error :

```
 fatal error: 'boost/uuid/uuid.hpp' file not found
```

Can somebody tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to run b2 with sudo.  You did that with `sudo ./b2 --with=all -j $cpuCores install` but not when you did `./b2 install threading=multi link=shared` What was the error generated when you did `sudo ./b2 --with=all -j $cpuCores install` ?

Comment: Hey..I tried  ``sudo ./b2 install threading=multi link=shared && ln -svf detail/sha1.hpp /usr/include/boost/uuid/sha1.hpp`` . It gives same result  ``ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/include/boost/uuid/sha1.hpp' Permission denied``.  And no error for ``sudo ./b2 --with=all -j $cpuCores install ``

Comment: So the `ln -svf` command needs sudo as well.  Whenever you want to do something to a directory not owned by your user you need sudo.  I don't see why you are doing this second b2 command at all if `sudo ./b2 --with=all -j $cpuCores install` worked without error.

Comment: Got it. Now I tried ``sudo ln -svf detail/sha1.hpp /usr/include/boost/uuid/sha1.hpp``. Now it runs successfully. But the ``fatal error: 'boost/uuid/uuid.hpp' file not found`` is the same.

Answer (score 3):

I  got a similar problem while installing AlmaBTE in ubuntu 20.04

```
/home/sy/applications/almabte-v1.3.2/src/superlattice_builder.cpp:38:10: fatal error: boost/uuid/sha1.hpp: No such file or directory
   38 | #include <boost/uuid/sha1.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/superlattice_builder.dir/build.make:63: src/CMakeFiles/superlattice_builder.dir/superlattice_builder.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:474: src/CMakeFiles/superlattice_builder.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:95: all] Error 2
```

The boost library was okay, however, I find the file 'sha1.hpp' located in another dir. So I just copied it to the right place and it worked;

```
sudo cp /usr/include/boost/uuid/detail/sha1.hpp /usr/include/boost/uuid/
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed all your steps and compiled this code

```
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    boost::uuids::uuid uuid = boost::uuids::random_generator()();
    std::cout << uuid << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled with
`c++ -Wall -std=c++17 -g -I /usr/local/include/ uuid_test.cpp -o uuid_test`
and it worked fine. Telling the linker where to find the uuid.hpp is done with the `-I` flag.